# documentation: the tour page suggests "take the tour"

Tags: bug, status-declined, documentation

When I start the tour I find [image] at the top - slightly superfluous I'd say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just because we have a big-ol' system message up for all of `/documentation` right now.  That message will go away eventually.